# Sitecore How to specify Data field type when adding a field by Template.AddField(string, string);

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

If I have a Sitecore Item `item` and I add a Data field "My Field" to it using:

```
 item.Template.AddField("My Field", "Data");
```

How Can I specify the field type for it. e.g `Single-Line Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddField(...)` method returns the added template field (it doesn't have a type yet).

You can then set the type on the template field like this:

```cs
var templateField = item.Template.AddField("Field name", "Section name");

using (new EditContext(templateField.InnerItem)) {
    templateField.Type = "Single-Line Text";
}
```

The type value should correspond to the name of the field type - e.g. `Single-Line Text`, `Rich Text`, `Grouped Droplist` etc.

Depending on your security you might also need to add the whole thing in a `SecurityDisabler`.

```cs
using (new SecurityDisabler()) {
    var templateField = item.Template.AddField("Field name", "Section name");

    using (new EditContext(templateField.InnerItem)) {
        templateField.Type = "Single-Line Text";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `xx.Type = "Single-Line Text";` I was really missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using next code:

```
 private void AddFieldToTemplate(string fieldName, string templatePath)
{
    const string templateOftemplateFieldId = "{453A3E98-FD4G-AGBF-EFTE-E683A0331AC7}";

    // this will do on your "master" database, consider Sitecore.Context.Database if you need "web"
    var templateItem = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(tempatePath);
    if (templateItem != null)
    {
        var templateSection = templateItem.Children.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Template.Name == "Template section");
        if (templateSection != null)
        {
            var newField = templateSection.Add(fieldName, new TemplateID(new ID(templateOftemplateFieldId)));
            using (new EditContext(newField))
            {
                newField["Type"] = "Text"; // text stands for single-line lext field type
            }
        }
        else
        { 
          add a new section template here 
        }
    }
}
```

You will add new field using next line of code:

```
  AddFieldToTemplate("New field","/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item");
```